# next.js file upload via api routes / formidable - not working

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, next.js, formidable

I'm having a hell of a time getting file upload to work via api routes.

On client-side im submitting the file like so:

```
 onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit

    this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response) => {
      console.log('rD', response.data)
    })
 }

 onFileChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })
 }

 fileUpload = (file) => {
    const url = '/api/mail/upload'
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', file)
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.props.session.csrfToken
      }
    }
    return axios.post(url, formData, config)
 }
```

My request to `/api/mail/upload` then looks like this:

```
Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1331
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBlNt6z8t4rGZT0x6
Cookie: abc123
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/new
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: abc123

Form Data:
file: (binary)
```

Then in the route (/api/mail/upload) I'm trying to use formidable to parse the form data and finally do something with the file.

I've made sure to disable the built-in body parser by including the following at the bottom of the api route file:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}
```

^^ Thats the correct way to do that, right?

Finally, in the api route, I've tried many different things, but currently the following is what I expect to work, but it is not..

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) return reject(err)
    console.log(fields, files)
    res.status(200).json({ fields, files })
  })
  // if I console.log(form) here - I can see the request details, so it seems to be picking that up
}
```

This generates no output whatsoever on the server-side nor on client-side, i expect the `console.log(fields, files)` to output on the server-side the name of the file, etc.

Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: In case anyone comes across this and has a similar issue - I didn't end up figuring this exact issue out, but I worked around it by using cloudinaries free service (ca. 25gb ~ month if you're just doing basic uploads of files without any transformations, etc.) using their example from on codepen (simple xhr upload): https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am 100% sure your issue is caused by intermixing CommonJS exports (i.e. `module.exports =` ) and ES6 modules syntax (`export const config = ...`).

When you do this NextJS sees only default export and doesn't see your config declaration and hence continues to parse body. Which, in turn, results in `req` to be already completed by the time it's being passed to `formidable`.

Apart from that everything looks right in your code. By just changing

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
```

to

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
```

you should get an expected behaviour.

Answer (score 26):

All you need is disable Next.js built-in body parser: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config

Here are working example:

```js
// Backend
import formidable from 'formidable';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "./";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(err, fields, files);
  });
};
```

https://gist.github.com/agmm/da47a027f3d73870020a5102388dd820

Comment: Yes, this works, indeed.

Comment: and `<form encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

Answer (score 6):

I believe that if you are doing asynchronous operations inside of the endpoint then next.js expects you to return a promise e.g

```
export default (req, res) => {
 const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve({fields, files});
  })

 })

 return promise.then(({fields, files}) => {
    res.status(200).json({ fields, files })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement it in a  simple way as explained below->

sending a file from client side in a simple way will be ->

client side->

```
const file = e.target.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

const { data } = await axios.post("/api/upload",formData)
```

install express-formidable at backend

backend api will be ->

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import formidable from 'express-formidable';

const router = express.Router();
export const config = {
    api: {
       bodyParser: false,
    },
};
     
export default router.post('/upload',formidable() ,expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const {file} = req.files;
    console.log(file);
    // here you can handle the incoming file to send it to cloud
      
}));
```

express-formidable will handle all the incoming stream and provide us data by storing all data to 'data' variable. In order to store it to any cloud (aws s3, cloudinary) , create a readable stream and append it to form data and then send it .

Comment: How to use bodyParser with ES6's module.exports ?