# How do I decode form data sent via fetch POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am sending form data with a basic POST request:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', '123');
const res = await fetch('./handler', { method: 'POST', body: formData });
const json = await res.json();
```

handler.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.id);
 ...
}
```

The code above will log `undefined`. When logging `req.body` the result is something that definitely needs decoding:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

123
------WebKitFormBoundary --
```

How do I read the data passed?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654747/parsing-post-form-data-node-js-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

in handler.js

```js
import formidable from 'formidable';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const form = formidable();

  form.parse(req, (err, fields) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(fields.id);
  });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to disable Next.js built-in body parser if you're using Next.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020241/next-js-file-upload-via-api-routes-formidable-not-working.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternooon,

You could try taking a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654747/parsing-post-form-data-node-js-express) and find out how to decode `formdata`.

However if you're intending to run this code in a browser import libraries is a hassle. In the event that the API is capable of responding with JSON, then I would recommend that since JS handles this without too much hassle.

You can try to request the data as JSON by adding the `Accept` header:

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // what you're sending
    "Accept": "application/json" // what you expect back
  }
}
```

You could alternatively also just send JSON ()

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', '123');

// would become
const reqBody = { id: 123 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `req.body.id` to get the outcome of '123'. Fetch treats form data as JSON IIRC.